# Write the matching values in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets.

[image]

The first sheet matches the dates without price, and the second sheet matches the dates with price. I want to compare the two dates and if they are equal I want to put the right price into the B colume, so that it looks like that:

[image]

I want to implement this with a excel formula. However, I have no idea where *to start*.

I appreciate your answer!!!

PS.: My `excel version` is `2010`

Comment: @Why downvoted? Please `downvoter` comment what is wrong with my question, so that I can fix that!

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I can easily guess why it was downvoted. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Paradox on SO: programmer expects initial attempts <-> user has no idea where to start :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `vlookup()` formula in the cells in column B:

```
=vlookup(A2,E1:F4,2;0)
```

Where the **first value** (A2) is the value you want to look up.

The **second value** (E1:F4) is the table where you want to look your value up.

The **third value** (2) is the column number of your table where you want to look the value up.

Remember, the **fourth value** is always 0 (or false).